# RegEx Regular Expression to get ID

Tags: php, regex

Given a string of the following:

- [download id="1"]
- [download id="1" attr=""]
- [download attr="" id="1"]
- [download attr="" id="1" attr=""]

ID is always a number. I need a regular expression that will always give me that number to be used via PHP preferably demonstrated via http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php.

Comment: Regular expressions are not parsers.

Comment: Is this the whole string, or is it a part of a bigger string? Can you give a more complete example?

Comment: Why ask for a regex?  Ask about the problem you face, namely extracting the value of an `id` attribute.  Don't ask for a particular solution mechanism.  [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: These are the various possible strings that could be.

Comment: You realise that numeric `id`s, or an `id` starting with a numeric character, is invalid outside of HTML5..?

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/id="(\d+)"/', $data, $matches);
```

Comment: that will match also squid="123"

Comment: @WalterTross, which is not in the possible strings ;)

Comment: until a squid sneaks in one day

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
/\[download.*?id=\"(\d+)\"/
```

Function called:

```
preg_match_all('/\[download.*?id=\"(\d+)\"/', '{{your data}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will always have one `id` field and that it will always be enclosed within quotes (`"`), you can try something like a regular expression like so: `id="(\d+)"`. This will capture the number and put it in a group. You can take a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) to see how you can then access these groups.

As it has been suggested, should you want to match more fields, I would recommend you drop regular expressions and find something which is able to parse the string you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

This would also be a solution

```
\[download[^\]]*id="(\d*)
```

You find your result in capturing group 1

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31bji)

`\[download` match "[download"

`[^\]]*` is a negated character class, matches everything that is not a "]" (o or more times)

`id="` matches "id="" literally

`(\d*)` is a capturing group that matches 0 or more digits, you can change the `*` to a `+` to match one or more.

<sub>[What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

you can use easily ini files and not regex in needed, for example:

test.ini

```
[download]
id=1
attr = ""
[download2]
id=2
attr = "d2"
```

and index.php

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('test.ini', true);
print_r($ini);
```

Comment: This is a very weird answer. Why do you assume the OP has any choice in the format? And even then - ini?! I'd think there are better alternatives now days...

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
<?php

    $content =
<<<TEST
[download id="1"]
[download id="2" attr=""]
[download attr="" id="3"]
[download attr="" id="4" attr=""]
TEST;

    $pattern = '/\[download.*[ ]+id="(?P<id>[0-9]+)".*\]/u';

    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches))
        var_dump($matches);

?>
```

Works with a single line input (read in **$matches['id'][0]**) or with a multiple lines input (like the example, iterating on **$matches['id']** array).

Note:

- Don't use preg_match with start **^** and end **$** delimiters, use instead **preg_match_all** without delimiters
- Don't use the "s" PCRE_DOTALL modifier
- Use the "i" modifier if you want the regex works with both "download" or "DOWNLOAD"
- Use the "u" modifier if the input is an UTF-8 encoded string

http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

http://it.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

The above example will output this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "[download id="1"]"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "[download id="2" attr=""]"
    [2]=>
    string(25) "[download attr="" id="3"]"
    [3]=>
    string(33) "[download attr="" id="4" attr=""]"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
}
```

So, you can read the ID attributes looping on **$matches['id']** array :)